# Copy path from vim netrw

Tags: vim

I use vim's netrw to explore some files. How can I copy the absolute path of the currently selected directory in netrw to a register and use it to paste into another buffer?

Comment: See also vim.stackexchange

Comment: @JeffSchaller http://vi.stackexchange.com/ is the link.

Comment: I don't understand what "use it to yank into another buffer" is supposed to mean.  "yank" is a synonym for "copy."  Did you mean "put" (paste) it into another buffer?

Comment: @Wildcard yes, sorry, I meant "paste". (I edited my Question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my netrw, the current directory path shows up in line 3 of the listing:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v140)
"   /Users/guido/Desktop
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
" ============================================================================
../                                                                                            
.DS_Store*
.localized
```

So, `:norm 3G5|y$` will yank the path into the current buffer. You could remap this to your liking.